# SQL: Rolling sum in the last 30 days by groups

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table as below:

```
date, custid, sales
2015-01-01, 01, 100
2015-01-10, 01, 200
2015-02-05, 01, 300
2015-03-02, 01, 400
2015-03-03, 01, 500
2015-01-01, 02, 100
2015-01-10, 02, 200
2015-02-05, 02, 300
2015-03-02, 02, 400
2015-03-03, 02, 500
...
```

How can I generate the rolling sum of sales of last 30 days by date and by custid.

The desired output would be:

```
date, custid, running_30_day_sales
2015-01-01, 01, 100
2015-01-10, 01, 300 --(100+200)
2015-02-05, 01, 500 --(200+300)
2015-03-02, 01, 700 --(300+400)
2015-03-03, 01, 1200 -- (300+400+500)
2015-01-01, 02, 100
2015-01-10, 02, 300 --(100+200)
2015-02-05, 02, 500 --(200+300)
2015-03-02, 02, 700 --(300+400)
2015-03-03, 02, 1200 -- (300+400+500)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is one way to do it using `self join`. Each date is joined with all the dates whose datediff is >0 and <= 30. Thereafter, it is just a grouping operation.

```
select a1.custid, a1.dt, a1.sales+sum(coalesce(a2.sales,0)) total
from atable a1
left join atable a2 on a1.custid=a2.custid 
and datediff(day,a2.dt,a1.dt)<=30 and datediff(day,a2.dt,a1.dt)>0
group by a1.custid,a1.dt,a1.sales
order by 1,2
```

[`Sample Demo in Postgres`](http://rextester.com/CPUU47349)

To understand it better, look at the query result of self-join using

```
select a1.*,a2.*
from atable a1
left join atable a2 on a1.custid=a2.custid 
and datediff(day,a1.dt,a2.dt)<=30 and datediff(day,a1.dt,a2.dt)>0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trick to do this using a cumulative sum:

```
with t as (
      select custid, date, sales from atable
      union all
      select custid, date + interval '30 day', sales from atable
     )
select custid, date,
       sum(sum(sales)) over (partition by cust_id order by date rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as sales_30day
from t
group by custid, date;
```

Comment: i think this will generate rows that are not in the table.

Comment: Hey Gordon, thanks for the reply. Can you please add a bit comment? Also when I ran the query on redshift I got an error "ERROR: 42601: Aggregate window functions with an ORDER BY clause require a frame clause"

Comment: @vip . . . Yes, you are correct.  This will have all dates where the value change.  If the OP wants to filter only for the dates in the original data, that is easy enough with another join.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a window function to find it this way

```
SELECT custid, dt::date,
            SUM(sales) OVER (partition by custid ORDER BY dt
                            RANGE BETWEEN '30 days' PRECEDING AND '2 days' Following) as  sum_of_sales
            MIN(sales) OVER (partition by custid ORDER BY dt::date
                            RANGE BETWEEN '30 days' PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as  minimum,
            MAX(sales) OVER (partition by custid ORDER BY dt::date
                            RANGE BETWEEN '2 days' PRECEDING AND '2 days' Following) as  maximum
      FROM atable
```